# How to optimize Mysql Query which has HAVING Clause?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

While I execute below query, it's scanning all rows from the table **b** to get the result. How to solve this issue, I already tried indexing the `product_id` and `product_category_variants_values_id` from table be. Even tho, I am getting the same effect.

```
SELECT
    a.product_id, a.product_name, a.product_qty, a.product_stock_status, a.product_type,
    a.product_mode, a.slug, a.product_price, a.product_sales_price 
FROM `product_meta` a 
JOIN `product_variants` b ON a.product_id = b.product_id 
WHERE a.product_category = 1 AND 
    CASE
        WHEN a.product_sales_price>0 THEN a.product_sales_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
        ELSE a.product_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
    END 
GROUP BY a.product_id 
HAVING SUM(b.product_category_variants_values_id = 24)
AND SUM(b.product_category_variants_values_id = 9);
```

Query of Table a :

```
    CREATE TABLE `product_meta` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_price` int(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `product_sales_price` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_qty` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `product_stock_status` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `product_category` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `product_tag` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `product_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_mode` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `slug` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `product_category_search` (`product_category`),
  KEY `product_tag_search` (`product_tag`),
  KEY `indx_slug` (`slug`)
)
```

Query of Table b :

```
            CREATE TABLE `product_variants` (
  `product_variants_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `product_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `product_category_variants_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `product_category_variants_values_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_variants_id`),
  KEY `indx_product_id_product_category_variants_values_id` (`product_category_variants_values_id`,`product_id`)
)
```

Query explain result,

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b | ALL | indx_product_id | NULL | NULL | NULL | 26287 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | a | eq_ref | PRIMARY,product_category_search | PRIMARY | 4 | v3.b.product_id | 1 | Using where |

Kindly tell me what to do to reduce the complete row scanning from table b.

Comment: I updated the question as like you said.

Comment: still it checking all rows of table b. I already added Index to product_id and product_category_variants_values_id in table b.

Comment: I updated the question again with the added index to table b

Comment: That's a weird `HAVING SUM(b..._id = 24) AND SUM(b..._id = 9)` -- It is `TRUE` only when some rows have 24 and some rows have 9.  Is that the intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a composite index on `(b.product_category_variants_values_id, b.product_id)`:

```
ALTER TABLE product_variants
    ADD KEY (product_category_variants_values_id, product_id)
```

Because the column being indexed is a `VARCHAR` you should quote the integer values being passed in, to avoid implicit type conversion.

Move the product variant criteria to the join and change the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    pm.product_id, pm.product_name, pm.product_qty, pm.product_stock_status, pm.product_type,
    pm.product_mode, pm.slug, pm.product_price, pm.product_sales_price 
FROM `product_meta` `pm` 
JOIN `product_variants` `pv`
    ON pm.product_id = pv.product_id
    AND pv.product_category_variants_values_id IN ('24', '9')
WHERE pm.product_category = 1 AND 
    CASE
        WHEN pm.product_sales_price > 0 THEN pm.product_sales_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
        ELSE pm.product_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
    END 
GROUP BY pm.product_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pv.product_category_variants_values_id) = 2;
```

Moving the aggregation into a subquery might give slightly better performance, depending on the distribution of your data:

```
SELECT
    pm.product_id, pm.product_name, pm.product_qty, pm.product_stock_status, pm.product_type,
    pm.product_mode, pm.slug, pm.product_price, pm.product_sales_price
FROM product_meta pm
JOIN (
    SELECT product_id
    FROM product_variants
    WHERE product_category_variants_values_id IN ('24', '9')
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_category_variants_values_id) = 2
) pv ON pm.product_id = pv.product_id
WHERE pm.product_category = 1 AND
    CASE
        WHEN pm.product_sales_price>0 THEN pm.product_sales_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
        ELSE pm.product_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
    END;
```

Or, you could move the `pv` criteria to separate `EXISTS` (probably more efficient):

```
SELECT
    pm.product_id, pm.product_name, pm.product_qty, pm.product_stock_status, pm.product_type,
    pm.product_mode, pm.slug, pm.product_price, pm.product_sales_price 
FROM `product_meta` `pm` 
WHERE pm.product_category = 1 AND 
    CASE
        WHEN pm.product_sales_price > 0 THEN pm.product_sales_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
        ELSE pm.product_price BETWEEN 0 AND 100000
    END
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_variants WHERE product_id = pm.product_id AND product_category_variants_values_id = '24')
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM product_variants WHERE product_id = pm.product_id AND product_category_variants_values_id = '9');
```

YMMV, give them both a try.

Comment: I updated the question and added the composite index to table b but still the same result. It's going through all the records in table b.

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed it at first. Because `product_category_variants_values_id` is a `VARCHAR`, you need to pass the integer values in as strings to avoid implicit type conversion.

Comment: Thanks man. I got the problem solved with the same query i shared in the question by changing `product_category_variants_values_id ` to INT from VARCHAR.

Comment: You should still avoid that original query. If you compare the two queries, you will notice there is an order of magnitude difference in overhead. Averaged over 10 runs your original query took 0.097s. The subquery variant above took 0.004s.

Comment: Yes, the last query you shared is a bit faster. Thanks again.